# When I introduce an abbreviation in a title, should I introduce the abbreviation again in the text that follows?

Tags: abbreviations

When I introduce an abbreviation in a title, should I introduce the abbreviation again in the text that follows?

Example:

[image]

vs.

[image]

Comment: This might be a better question for Writers SE as this is not really a language question. Personally, I think it is OK to write the full term and abbreviation the first timer it appears in the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't really a rule. Its a matter of style and taste.

Personally, I don't like to be redundant. I would only write it once.